# Executing XmlTransform in Wix instead of on compile

Tags: c#, wix

I have a solution where I have different app.configs, given a different configuration. Drawback is that an installer (created using Wix) is created for a specific configuration. I would like to do this on install time, such that I can start the installer with a command line parameter to do the xml transformation, to be able to use the same installer in different environemnts (development, test, accpetance).

So, currently I have the transform in the csproj file:

`<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="App.config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).exe.config" />
  </Target>`

What I want to do is:

`msiexec /i installer.msi PROD`

such that the transformation in app.PROD.config is executed. Is there a way in Wix to achieve that using the transformations?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transforming the original file at install time, it is easier to include all transformed app.config files into the MSI package and then choose the appropriate one during at install by passing the property value.

The snippet of the `wxs` file might look like this:

```
<Component Id="AppConfigDev" Guid="...">
  <Condition>MODE = "DEV"</Condition>
  <File Name="app.config" Id="app.dev.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Source)\app.DEV.config" />
</Component>
<Component Id="AppConfigTest" Guid="...">
  <Condition>MODE = "TEST"</Condition>
  <File Name="app.config" Id="app.test.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Source)\app.TEST.config" />
</Component>
<Component Id="AppConfigProd" Guid="...">
  <Condition>MODE = "PROD"</Condition>
  <File Name="app.config" Id="app.prod.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Source)\app.PROD.config" />
</Component>
```

As a result, when you pass in the value of `MODE` through the command line, only one of the components above will be installed, and it will end up in the target directory as `app.config`.

Note that Windows Installer will throw a warning saying the conditions must be mutually exclusive in order for this technique to work. As long as `MODE` property can only have one value at a time, these conditions are mutually exclusive by definition, but the warning is there.